# aws_availability_zones returns an availability zone ap-southeast-2c that is not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I'm attempting to create an AWS RDS Serverless v2 cluster in region `ap-southeast-2` (Sydney) using the following Terraform configuration:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-southeast-2"
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "backend_app_db_cluster" {
  availability_zones = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  # ...
}
```

When I try to `apply` this configuration, I get the following error:

> InvalidVPCNetworkStateFault: Availability zone '[ap-southeast-2c]' is unavailable in this region, please choose another zone set.

Full output:

```
module.database.aws_rds_cluster.backend_app_db_cluster: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating RDS Cluster (<munged>20221204221217538100000001): InvalidVPCNetworkStateFault: Availability zone '[ap-southeast-2c]' is unavailable in this region, please choose another zone set.
│   status code: 400, request id: <munged>
│
│   with module.database.aws_rds_cluster.backend_app_db_cluster,
│   on modules/database/main.tf line 54, in resource "aws_rds_cluster" "backend_app_db_cluster":
│   54: resource "aws_rds_cluster" "backend_app_db_cluster" {
```

If I specify the availability zones manually and specifically exclude `ap-southeast-2c`, it works as expected:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  exclude_names = ["ap-southeast-2c"]
  state         = "available"
}
```

```
$ terraform apply
...
module.database.aws_rds_cluster_instance.backend_app_db_cluster_instance: Creation complete after 12m43s [id=tf-<munged>]

Apply complete! Resources: 3 added, 0 changed, 1 destroyed.
```

Why is `aws_availability_zones` returning an AZ that's unavailable?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a subnet in ap-southwest-2c? In order to build the the Subnet group for RDS you have to have subnets in all AZs. If you don't have, Terraform throws this error received from API.